# Re-write url reuse of file name as their base parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-routing

Well it was kind of difficult what wordings for the title, yet I'm quite interested how this thing works.

Assuming that I have this .htaccess on my root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For example

I have this url that consists of whatever content it has.

```
www.myurl.com/foo
```

Then if I go to other page it would be like

```
www.myurl.com/foo/bar
```

So meaning, I'm using the `foo` as their base once I redirect to other pages.

So my structure of root folder is..

```
index.php
foo.php
bar.php
```

So if `www.myurl.com/foo` I'm opening the `foo.php`, but then if I access `www.myurl.com/foo/bar` I'm opening `bar.php` with a base of file name of `foo.php`. Logically thinking it's wrong.

But are there any way of doing this?

Real live desired result is..

`www.myurl.com/campaigns`

if I go to child page of campaigns it would be

`www.myurl.com/campaigns/create`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you need a router; Apache rewrite tools are not suited to handling this alone. Typically you use a front controller (often called index.php) that everything is rewritten to, passing the whole url as a parameter. The front controller then starts the router, which fires up the correct controller to handle the request.

Your .htaccess then looks something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Take a look at the [Symfony router component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), and read the first chapter of the [Symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html) for the general idea of how that all works.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, Thanks for the answer @Bryan Agee.

I've found a great site that talks about URL Rewriting, especially for the people who doesn't even know how it works including me.

To anyone interested, here's the link of it.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

It's very easy to understand.

For the solution on my problem, here it is.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^campaigns/?$             src/campaigns/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule   ^campaigns/create/?$          src/campaigns/create.php [NC]
```

And if I want to put parameters on the link

```
#RewriteRule   ^campaigns/create/(.+)$   src/campaigns/create.php?cid=$1 [L]
```

For furthermore understanding, visit the link above. :D